# Mediawiki Upgrade Failure: Could not open "patch-indexes.sql"

Tags: mediawiki-installation

I'm attempting an upgrade from mediawiki from 1.24.4 to 1.32.0 on a shared hosting platform (Dreamhost). The upgrade appears to be bombing out trying to open the patch-indexes.sql file. Permissions on the file are (-rw-r--r--).

Error message:

```
Turning off Content Handler DB fields for this part of upgrade.
...have ipb_id field in ipblocks table.
...have ipb_expiry field in ipblocks table.
...already have interwiki table
Updating indexes to 20031107 ...
An error occurred:
Could not open "patch-indexes.sql".
Purging caches...done.
```

I'm wondering if anyone has solved this problem before.

Comment: Add some debug output [here](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/0abb9338f870824e258a7a138ad07efbaa6b3894/includes/installer/DatabaseUpdater.php#L679) to see if it is looking for the file in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The reason for this was the incomplete database. I had to update from 1.24.4 to 1.31.1 and the rebuild of the database broke on the new server with phpMyAdmin. After I had chosen another software to create the database (e.g. mySQLDumper) it works fine.

Paul